# How to use after insert trigger to send e-mail

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to send an e-mail alert after inserting a new data to my sql server data table. How can i do this?

I have tried following trigger, but i'm no pretty sure about the functionality of it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.sendMail 
   ON  dbo.staff_leaves
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @to = 'whoever@yourcompany.com', 
          @profile_name = 'default',
          @subject = 'New Row', 
          @body = 'Yep, they sure were.';

END
GO
```

Anyone please explain me how to do this.

Comment: Please have a look **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29060/SQL-SERVER-2008-Configure-Database-Mail-Send-Email**

Answer (score 1):

You write that you are not pretty sure about the functionality but it is not clear what makes you unsure. Have you done a test run?

I suggest to check out the MSDN page for [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) which provides a nearly identical code sample and contains a bunch of other tips too. For example, MSDN recommends that:

> Before use, Database Mail must be enabled using the Database Mail
>   Configuration Wizard, or sp_configure.

and

> Execute permissions (are required) for sp_send_dbmail default to all members of the
>   DatabaseMailUser database role in the msdb database. However, when the
>   user sending the message does not have permission to use the profile
>   for the request, sp_send_dbmail returns an error and does not send the
>   message.

Step-by-step description can be found at [Database Mail set up in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/databaseexpertisecom/2010/05/12/database-mail-set-up-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Where can i access Database Mail Configuration Wizard ? Please explain me.