# Better technique to send mail if new record inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form to fill details, those records will inserted in db with columns name, email, phone, ismailsent. now i want to send an email to my admin team if any new record inserted into DB. any better technique like windows service, i want it to be very clean. any help appriciated

Comment: Show your current effort

Comment: i thought create `sql server trigger` is better than create window service. or after you insert value you send email with c# mail functionality

Comment: @sabil that might put too much load on db right. i am looking for faster and lighter way

Comment: @charan so why not try to send email, after you success insert the data on your c# code behind, or if you use SP, how about insert email code there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any details, but I guess you're looking for something like a database trigger. I don't know which DBMS you're using, but take a look at this post: [C# / SQL Listener to tell me if a row has been inserted into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365026/c-sharp-sql-listener-to-tell-me-if-a-row-has-been-inserted-into-a-table)

Comment: Then this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355921/sql-server-2008-help-writing-simple-insert-trigger

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for achieving this functionality, you could have a windows service or a web service which you invoke after you insert your record successfully, or you could use the SQL Server 2008 build in functionality (sp_send_dbmail), but you first need to configure it. Here are some posts that might help you:

- [How to use after insert trigger to send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601826/how-to-use-after-insert-trigger-to-send-e-mail)
- [MSDN about sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)
- [Configuring mail functionality in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/databaseexpertisecom/2010/05/12/database-mail-set-up-in-sql-server-2008/)

Hope it helps. Cheers!